# How to replace preg named group with values from array with corresponding keys?

Tags: php, regex

I have some preg patterns for parse data. But now I need to do the inverse problem. Substitute my data in the exists preg patterns. For example string patterns:

```
something(?<value>\d+)something
another(?P<id>\d+)another
someone(?'number'\d+)someone
```

And example array:

```php
[
'value' => 'something',
'id' => '123',
'number' => '828',
];
```

Example result:

```
somethingsomethingsomething
another123another
someone828someone
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamic replacement, you might use a pattern with 2 capturing groups. In the first group you capture what you want to keep in the replacement.

The value of the second capturing group could be used as a key to index into the example array.

You might use and [preg_match_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)  to return the replacement string.

If the text before and after that capturing group should be the same, you could use of a backreference `\1`

```
([^(\r\n]+)\(\?(?|P?<([^>]+)>|'([^']+)')[^)\r\n]+\)\1
```

About the pattern

- `([^(\r\n]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times any char except `(` or a newline
- `\(\?` Match `(?`
- `(?|` Branch reset group, which will be **group 2**

  - `P?<([^>]+)>` Match an optional `P` and capture in a group what is between `<` and `>`
  - `|` Or
  - `'([^']+)'` Capture in a group what is between `'`
- `)` Close branch reset group
- `[^)\r\n]+\)` Match 1+ times any char except `)` or a newline, then match `)`
- `\1` backreference to group 1

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJUwWz/1/) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/qHqKJ)

For example

```
$exampleArray = [
    'value' => 'something',
    'id' => '123',
    'number' => '828',
];

$re = '/([^(\r\n]+)\(\?(?|P?<([^>]+)>|\'([^\']+)\')[^)\r\n]+\)\1/';
$str = <<<STR
something(?<value>\d+)something
another(?P<id>\d+)another
someone(?'number'\d+)someone
STR;

$result =preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) use ($exampleArray) {
    return $m[1] . $exampleArray[$m[2]] . $m[1];
}, $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
somethingsomethingsomething
another123another
someone828someone
```